# Install issue with Terraform on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, zip, wget, terraform

Whenever I run a terraform install on linux using:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.14/terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip
sudo unzip ./terraform_0.11.13_linux_amd64.zip
sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
```

It only unzips a file and it does not seem to install.  I am not sure if this is what suppose to happen, but I assume it is not suppose to be that as I can not add it to my path.

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/install.html :

```
After downloading Terraform, unzip the package. Terraform runs as a single binary named terraform. Any other files in the package can be safely removed and Terraform will still function.
```

So if you move the binary anywhere in your PATH, you should be able to run it.

run `echo $PATH` to see what directories your PATH contains.